# Почему долгий sync Gradle Product Flavors?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle

У меня многомодульная (20 модулей) архитектура и достаточно много product flavors (16 шт) + 3 build types. Синхронизация проекта возрастает в геометрической прогрессии. Возможно я что то делаю не так? Есть ли хорошие статьи по оптимизации подобных случаев? Почти все протыкал на гугле и медиуме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы заключалась в том, что gradle при создании buildVariants синхронизировал все возможные варианты, а не один активный. В экспериментальных функция есть опция “Only sync the active variant”, но работает она только с Java модулями или C++.

Проблема решена! В новой Android Studio ArctixFox + Gradle 7 добавлена поддержка Kotlin